# Django:Admin List_display is not working for one specific model

Tags: python, django, admin

I am building an app. I am trying do display fields for 2 different model. Consultation and Consultationserie. The list_display function works for consultationserie but not for consultation. It only shows one field (start_date). There is a foriegnkey of linking to a consultationserie type in the consultation model. I wonder if it is causing a problem. I added to create a parent to child relationship between consultationserie and consultation.
Thank you in advance for your help

I tried to use different register method (With the decorator, with admin.site.register, admin.site.register(Consultation,ConsultationAdmmin)).

Models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
import uuid
from datetime import date
from django.urls import reverse # Used to generate URLs by reversing the URL patterns

class ConsultationSerie(models.Model):
    """Model representing a consultation process (define by the relationship between a patient and a doctor) but notr a specific consultation"""
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, help_text = 'Unique ID for this particular Consultation process' )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    patient = models.ForeignKey('Patient', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey('Doctor', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        "Number representing the consultation process"
#        return str(self.id)
        return self.patient.lastname + "&" + self.doctor.lastname 

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Returns the url to access a detail record for this consultation process"""
        return reverse('consultation-detail',args=[str(self.id)])

class Consultation(models.Model):
    """Model representing a specific consultation"""
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, help_text='Unique ID for this particular consultation')
#    consultationserie = models.ForeignKey(ConsultationSerie, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    CONSULTATION_STATUS = (
        ('o', 'reserved'),
        ('c', 'cancelled'),
        ('a', 'ajourned'),
        ('d', 'done'),
        )

    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=CONSULTATION_STATUS,
        blank=True,
        default='o',
        help_text='Consultation status',
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['start_date']

    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the Model object."""
#        return f'{self.id} ({self.consultationserie.id})'
        return str(self.start_date) 


    @property
    def is_passed(self):
        if self.end_date and date.today() > self.end_date:
            return True
        return False
```

Admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from monkyrosite.models import id_adress, Patient, Doctor, PatientInstance, DoctorInstance, ConsultationSerie, Consultation

admin.site.register(id_adress)
admin.site.register(Patient)
admin.site.register(PatientInstance)
admin.site.register(Doctor)
admin.site.register(DoctorInstance) 

@admin.register(ConsultationSerie)
class ConsultationSerie(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id','doctor','patient')

    fieldsets = (
        (None,{
            'fields':('patient','doctor','id')
        }),
        )

@admin.register(Consultation)
class Consultation(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_diplay = ('status','start_date','end_date')

    fieldsets = (
        (None,{
            'fields': ('status','start_date','end_date')
            }),
        )
```

The result expected is the start_date end_date and status showing in the admin window when I click on the Consultationslink in Django Admin.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: If you don't write the class in the admin.py to show it, only the register method, does the fields appear in Admin Panel?

Comment: @Zoro-Zen - Unfortunately even without writing the class in the admin.py, it only shows the start_date field...

Comment: Have you done the migration command right? `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: Sorry, for the delay. I put django on hold for a little while. Yes, I did the migration the right way.